# crop a square image in hexagon using swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

How can we crop a square image in hexagon using swift. I want to use a square image and crop /clip into hexagon. EG. Instagram profile picture (but in hexagon instead of circle) in swift

Comment: The answer to this question will have very little to do with Swift or Xcode. The solution will probably involve masking images using Core Graphics...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create the shape and save it as an image, then do an image mask. This is a portion of code I was using to do the exact same thing, but you will need to create your own size and rect variables. Hope this helps.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
UIImage(CGImage: originalImage!).drawInRect(rect)
maskImage.drawInRect(rect, blendMode: CGBlendMode.DestinationIn, alpha: 1.0)
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
imageView.image = newImage
```